# В массив попадают неправильные данные (живёт своей жизнью) Golang

Tags: golang

Не понимаю почему в ВЕСЬ массив зменяется значением `currentArray`.

C каждым новым добавлением `append` к `arrayResult` ВСЕ элементы в массиве меняются на currentArray. Как решить эту проблему?

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
    array := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(permute(array))
}


func permute(nums []int) [][]int {
    if(len(nums) < 2) {
        var arrayResult [][]int
        arrayResult = append(arrayResult, nums)
        return arrayResult
    }

    arrayResult := make([][]int, 1)
    arrayResult[0] = nums
    var currentArray = nums
    `fmt.Println(currentArray)` /// выводит [1, 2, 3]
    `fmt.Println(arrayResult)`  /// выводит [[1, 2, 3]]  

    for number := 0; number < (len(nums) - 1); {
        currentNumber := currentArray[number]
        currentArray[number] = currentArray[number + 1]
        currentArray[number + 1] = currentNumber
        `fmt.Println(currentArray)` /// [1, 2, 3] или [3, 2, 1] [2, 3, 1] (всегда уникальные значения)
        arrayResult = append(arrayResult, currentArray) /// добавляю в массив
        
        if(len(arrayResult) == (len(nums) * 2)){
            return arrayResult
        }
        if((number + 1) >= (len(nums) - 1)){
            number = 0
            continue
        }
        number++
    }
    
    return arrayResult /// выводит [[1 3 2] [1 3 2] [1 3 2] [1 3 2] [1 3 2] [1 3 2 ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все массивы в `arrayResult` указывают на одну и ту же область памяти. Неудивительно, что они все содержат одно и то же значение.

Вам необходимо добавлять в массив результатов копию массива:

```
        cloneArray := make([]int, len(currentArray))
        copy(cloneArray, currentArray)
        arrayResult = append(arrayResult, cloneArray) /// добавляю в массив
```

С такой заменой ваш вопрос решён: https://go.dev/play/p/qBUGxbAnS_6

```
[[1 3 2] [2 1 3] [2 3 1] [3 2 1] [3 1 2] [1 3 2]]
```

Но теперь видно, что ваш алгоритм неправильно считает перестановки. Как минимум вызывает удивление, что вы предполагаете, будто число результатов должно быть `2*len(nums)`, но на самом деле это должно быть факториалом от `len(nums)`.

Этим проблемы не исчерпываются. Замените вычисление длины массива результатов на факториал и попробуйте для примера посчитать перестановки четырёх элементов. Ваш алгоритм находит чуть больше половины (скрипт `go run main.go | sed -e 's/\] \[/\n/g;s/\[\|\]//g' | sort | uniq` ):

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 4 3
1 4 2 3
2 1 3 4
2 3 1 4
2 3 4 1
3 2 4 1
3 4 1 2
3 4 2 1
4 1 2 3
4 1 3 2
4 3 1 2
```

Для пяти чисел ситуация ещё хуже, всего 21 из 120. Дальше больше. Но как поправить алгоритм - это уже другой вопрос ;)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Вопрос был не в алгоритме) с алгоритмом буду додумывать сам) Спасибо за помощь, очень помогли)